# Unable to define a mapping including the '.' key

Tags: vim

I am trying to define a mapping for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> as follows:

```
  map <C-.> :bn<CR>
```

This does not work. Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> just results in repeating the last action just as you would get when typing <kbd>.</kbd>. Note that I do not want to change the behaviour of <kbd>.</kbd>. Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use xbindkeys to map `<C-.>` on some script that will send WINCH signal to the current vim window. This signal causes VimResized autocommands to run. It is the only way I figured out. Maybe you could modify your current keymap so that `<C-.>` will produce something different than a dot, but I do not know how you could do it.